# Changed font scaling, but now other apps (google chrome) are still tiny

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, vmware, display-resolution

So there's an option in Google Chrome to increase the page zoom or whatever, but what about font scaling? The URL text is still too tiny, the addon icons are still too tiny... it just simply doesn't do everything I need it to do.

Long story short, I have 4k monitors running Ubuntu in VMware Workstation and it seems that there's no solution to make the guest VMs to scale properly, so i'm forced to do things inside of the guest such as increase font scaling in system preferences, etc. However, this seems to be a hit or miss depending on the application I'm running.

Anyone know how I can fix this issue overall or at least increase the size of *everything* in google chrome instead of just the page fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to System Settings > Display and choose a lower resolution than 3840x2160, as I assume it is set currently. I would say that full HD (1920x1080) would be good, but you might want something a little higher resolution. While this solution works, depending on your application this may not work because native 4K content will only be played at the resolution that you pick.

Comment: This doesn't work in VMware Workstation. While the resolution of the guest VM changes, it actually just changes the size of the display and doesn't "stretch" or "scale" it. For example, 1080p makes the guest VM display shrink in size. It doesn't actually stretch the 1080p to fit the guest VM window.

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. I would have assumed that it would still work inside of a VM, but apparently not.